# Table values does not change in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Im fetching data from an API and changing the value from the frontend to display it in a table. Im fetching a list of objects and storing it in a state and displaying the objects in the state in a html table. The table has a checkbox to display a boolean value. If the value is true, then defaultChecked is true in the checkbox. There's a checkbox in the table header to check or uncheck all items.

The following is the json object which i fetch.

```
{
completed: false
id: 1
title: "delectus aut autem"
userId: 1
}
```

If I checked the checkbox in the table header, I want to set `completed` to `true` in all 200 items.

The following is the code to set all items to either true or false.

```
const checkAllHandler = (e) => {
    let val = e.target.checked;
    console.log(val);
    let allTodoList = [];

    if (val === true) {
      if (todo.length > 0) {
        
        for (let index = 0; index < todo.length; index++) {
          const newObject = {
            userId: todo[index].userId,
            id: todo[index].id,
            title: todo[index].title,
            completed: true,
          };
          allTodoList.push(newObject);
        }
        setTodo(allTodoList);
        
      }
    } else if (val === false) {
      if (todo.length > 0) {
       
        for (let index = 0; index < todo.length; index++) {
          const newObject = {
            userId: todo[index].userId,
            id: todo[index].id,
            title: todo[index].title,
            completed: false,
          };
          allTodoList.push(newObject);
        }
        setTodo(allTodoList);
        
      }
    }
  };
```

When I console the `todo` state, all the values are updated to either true or false but it doesnt show on the table.
The table has a filter function. If I filter a word and go back, then the values of entire table is changing. I want to display the change when the checkbox is clicked and not when search and go back. How to I do that?

The complete code of the component is below.

```
const DataTable = () => {
  const { loading, items } = useSelector((state) => state.allData);
  // console.log(items)

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // const history = useNavigate();

  const [searchText, setsearchText] = useState("");
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState(items);
  console.log("todo");
  console.log(todo);
  const [isFetch, setisFetch] = useState(false);
  const [checkedloading, setcheckedLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isChecked, setisChecked] = useState(false);
  console.log(isChecked);

  useEffect(() => {
    const setDataToState = () => {
      if (loading === false) {
        setTodo(items);
      }
    };
    setDataToState();
  }, [loading]);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    dispatch(getData());
    // setTodo(items)
    // console.log(items)
  }, [dispatch]);
  //etTodo(items)
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    //let value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    setsearchText(event.target.value);
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (e, item) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    console.log(item);

    if (e.target.checked === true) {
      // const item = todo.filter(x=> x.id === id)
      // console.log("added")
      // console.log(item)

      for (let index = 0; index < todo.length; index++) {
        if (todo[index].id === item.id) {
          console.log(todo[index]);
          console.log("deleting");
          todo.splice(index, 1);
          console.log("deleted");
          const newObject = {
            userId: item.userId,
            id: item.id,
            title: item.title,
            completed: true,
          };
          console.log("adding updated object");
          todo.splice(index, 0, newObject);
          console.log("added");

          console.log(todo);
        }
      }
    } else {
      // const item = todo.filter(x=> x.id === id)
      // console.log("removed")
      // console.log(item)
      for (let index = 0; index < todo.length; index++) {
        if (todo[index].id === item.id) {
          console.log(todo[index]);
          console.log("deleting");
          todo.splice(index, 1);
          console.log("deleted");
          const newObject = {
            userId: item.userId,
            id: item.id,
            title: item.title,
            completed: false,
          };
          console.log("adding updated object");
          todo.splice(index, 0, newObject);
          console.log("added");

          console.log(todo);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  const onSubmitHandler = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(todo));
  };
  const getItem = () => {
    const items = localStorage.getItem("items");
    console.log("local storage items");
    console.log(JSON.parse(items));
  };

  const checkAllHandler = async (e) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;
    console.log(checked);
    setTodo((todos) =>
      todos.map((todo) => ({
        ...todo,
        completed: checked,
      }))
    );
   
  };

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("todo in render")}
      {console.log(todo)}
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.top}>
          <div className={styles.search_bar}>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)}
              placeholder="search by name"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.btn_container}>
          <button onClick={onSubmitHandler}>Submit</button>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.data_table_container}>
          {checkedloading === false ? (
            <>
              <div className={styles.data_table}>
                {loading || todo === null || todo === undefined ? (
                  <>
                    <p>Loading!!</p>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>userId</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>
                          <>
                            Completed
                            <input type="checkbox" onChange={checkAllHandler} />
                          </>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                      <tbody>
                        {todo
                          .filter((val) => {
                            if (searchText === "") {
                              return val;
                            } else if (
                              val.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
                            ) {
                              return val;
                            }
                          })
                          .map((item) => (
                            <>
                              <tr key={item.id}>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{item.userId}</td>
                                <td>{item.title}</td>
                                <td>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    defaultChecked={item.completed}
                                    onClick={(e) => onChangeHandler(e, item)}
                                  />
                               
                                </td>
                               
                              </tr>
                            </>
                          ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>Loading</>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-proskuriakova-60t19

Comment: the code seems ok. the problem may caused somewhere else. also the code is bit of verbose. you can use map to refactor the code like setTodo(todo.map(e=>({...e, completed: val})))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any overt issues in this code, but it is quite verbose. Both logic branches are identical save for the `completed` boolean value assigned. When updating arrays in React it is common to use [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to make the shallow copy of *the previous state*, not whatever state may be closed over in the callback scope.

Example:

```
const checkAllHandler = (e) => {
  const { checked } = e.target;
  console.log(checked);
  setTodo(todos => todos.map(todo => ({
    ...todo,
    completed: checked,
  })));
};
```

If there's still further issue from here with updating the table then please add the rest of the component code and any other code you think is relevant.

### Update

The reason none of the checkbox inputs are changing in the table is because you've used the `defaultChecked` prop, which makes these inputs fully **uncontrolled** inputs. They take the initial `item.completed` value when mounted and don't change from there other than if you interact with the checkbox.

If you want them to respond to changes/updates to the `todo` state then they should be converted to fully ***controlled*** inputs and use the `checked` prop.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={item.completed}
  onClick={(e) => onChangeHandler(e, item)}
/>
```

[image: Edit dazzling-sunset-t5z80]

### Update #2

The individual checkbox inputs were being mutated with `Array.prototype.splice` in `onChangeHandler`. `.splice` does an in-place mutation. Again a functional state update should be used to shallow copy the previous state and check for the matched `todo` object by `id`.

```
const onChangeHandler = (e, item) => {
  const { checked } = e.target;

  setTodo((todos) =>
    todos.map((todo) =>
      todo.id === item.id
        ? {
            ...todo,
            completed: checked
          }
        : todo
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: the values are updating. the problem is it is not rendering the updated state. If I type something on the search text field, then only the updates are shown.

Comment: @Learnado Can you update your question with a more complete and comprehensive code example? Is it also possible to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: edited the question with complete source code and codesandbox link.

Comment: @Minsaf Ok, found that you were using uncontrolled vs controlled inputs, this is why they weren't updating. Added update to my answer.

Comment: Tried using checked property. It works for check or uncheck all the checkboxes but if I check a value in the table, the same thing happens, the data changing but not rendering.

Comment: @Minsaf I'll take another look, you had a lot of weird stuff in there.

Comment: @Minsaf Yeah, you were mutating the `todos` state with the array splicing. Check the codesandbox again. Functional state update is used again to shallow copy previous state to next. Don't mutate existing state.